# Swipeable page in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, touch, responsive-design

I have a web site (HTML5, CSS3) which I want to improve it by making it work on mobile devices. So, I reached to the point where I need to change the pages with a simple left or right swipe. I do not want to change the structure of my HTML documents.

I need it to look like any swipable component in a native mobile application, so when I'm in the middle of the process, I need to see a part of the second page, moving as I swipe.

Are there any good and responsive libraries what could help me with this on? Or do you know any techniques? Or maybe tutorials?

EDIT: I'm more interested now, that I saw the libraries, how can I pre-load the pages, in order to use the libraries and give that page-slide effect. This is my biggest concern.

Answer (score 1):

For swiping support you might want to take a look at

- [Flickable](http://lagoscript.org/jquery/flickable/demo) or
- [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4); They now have a project called [SwipeView](http://cubiq.org/swipeview)

Comment: Thumbs up for SwipeView - we have used a modified version of it for our major media website and it works well. We tried jQuery Mobile, but didn't like the way it seemed to force you to use a particular style of buttons and other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jquerymobile.com/ which is designed for Touchscreens and providing [Page transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

Comment: I took a look and I saw that it's changing your HTML page structure, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Hammer.js looks nice for gestures: http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/ , but it will require adding a class etc